# Linked list deleting last node c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am currently writing some code which will delete the last node from a linked list, i have the code below; but it is deleting the previous node to the last node; not the last node itself.

Any help will be appreciated:

```
if(p!=NULL) {
    if( p->next!=NULL) {
        Student *todel = p->next;       
        p->next= p->next->next;
        delete todel; //free(todel);
    } else {
        delete p; //If n = 0 && its the last element, delete it
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have now edited this code to look like the below......it is not working; is it because I am pointing to a NULL vaue, then deleting that null value?

```
if(p!=NULL) {
    if( p->next==NULL) {
            delete p;

  } 
}
```

Comment: If you plan to delete last node you have to check, that next element is NULL (i.e. at least put "if( p->next == NULL) )" in second line).

Comment: @user2799788 correctly said by llya, you should check like  if(p!=NULL)if(p->next==NULL){delete p;}

Comment: At least you need a while loop if your list contains two nodes or more.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.

```
    if(p!=NULL) {
    if ( p->next!=NULL) {
       while (1) {
        Student *todel = p->next;  
        if (todel->next == NULL) {
          // todel is indeed the last node, delete it
          delete todel;
          p->next = NULL;
          break; // break from infinite while loop that was looking for last node
        }
        else {
           // todel is not last node, go further
           p = todel->next;
        }
     }
  } else {
        delete p; //If n = 0 && its the last element, delete it

  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead inside the loop you are using to walk the linked list.

```
  if(p->next!=NULL) {
        if (p->next->next == NULL) {// Found the second-to-last-node
          delete p->next;  // Kill the last node
          p->next = NULL;  // Make the current node the last node.

      }
  }
```

Comment: hmmm, it is not entering the second if statement?

Comment: @user2799788, That means you have a bug elsewhere in your code, because `next` pointer in the last element of the linked list is supposed to point to `NULL`. If it is not entering the second `if` statement, it means that the statement above is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I didn't test it.

```
void delete_lastnode(Node* head)
{
    Node *p = head;

    if (p == NULL)  // NULL list
        return;

    if (p->next == NULL) // Single node list
    {
        delete head;
        head = NULL;
        return;
    }

    while(p->next->next != NULL) // Find the second-last node
    {
        p = p->next;
    }

    Node* temp = p->next;
    p->next = NULL;
    delete temp;
    temp = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however that deletes the first in the list, not the last.

Comment: Please give a case which I delete the first node if your list contains at least two nodes.

Comment: @user2799788 can you provide a test case which delete the first node?